# How to customize some header section of page in mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

How to customize some header section of page in mpdf ?

My example below works perpect, header and footer appear on every page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            header: page-header;
            footer: page-footer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <htmlpageheader name="page-header">
        Header Content
    </htmlpageheader>

    <htmlpagefooter name="page-footer">
        Footer Content
    </htmlpagefooter>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to customize the content of header and footer of some pages.

**Possible Output:**

***Page 1.***

```
---------------------------------------
Header Content Original ... some words
---------------------------------------

      CONTENT

--------------------------------------
Footer Content  Original ... some words
--------------------------------------
```

***Page 2.***

```
---------------------------------------
Header Content Duplicate ... some words
---------------------------------------

      CONTENT

--------------------------------------
Footer Content  Duplicate ... some words
--------------------------------------
```